# Qt QList<QString> serialization for database

Tags: qt, serialization, qtsql

I have a QList list. I want to insert it on the database. I didn't find any serializer method after some googling. If there any method / idea to serialize the list data for database?

Comment: If you mean a relational database, then the best way is not try to serialize it at all. That's what you have tables and columns for.

Comment: Are you planning to serialize the whole list and then insert it into a specific column? Please avoid it as it would be a really bad design.

Comment: You didn't find this?  http://lists.qt.nokia.com/pipermail/qt-interest/2011-July/035068.html

Comment: Of course it's bad design.  But he wasn't asking about design.

Comment: @SayemAhmed Yeah! But I'm already ahead with some codings. I need to finish it.

Comment: @Dewsworld: Did the solution work ?

Comment: @Dewsworld: What is going wrong? How are you inserting it into the database? Are you facing problems while serializing it?

Comment: @SayemAhmed When I'm fetching them with a **query** I get a size 0 for the data I've inserted with Streaming. Btw, I've change the insertion with a conversion from StringList to String, it's a bit ugly, but currently serving my purpose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about using `QStringList` instead of `QList<QString>` -

```
QStringList numberList_;    // instead of QList<QString>, use this
QString myString1 = "Hello";
QString myString2 = "World";
numberList_ << myString1;
numberList_ << myString2;

QByteArray byteArray;
QBuffer buffer(&byteArray);
QDataStream out(&buffer);
out << numberList_;
```

Probably `QList<QString>` should also work in place of `QStringList`. If it doesn't, well, you can convert it pretty easily to `QStringList`.

[QDataStream](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qdatastream.html), [QBuffer](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qbuffer.html), 
[QByteArray](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qbytearray.html) and [QStringList](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qstringlist.html) reference.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another option that is a bit more succinct:

```
QString serialize(QStringList stringList)
{
  QByteArray byteArray;
  QDataStream out(&byteArray, QIODevice::WriteOnly);
  out << stringList;
  return QString(byteArray.toBase64());
}

QStringList deserialize(QString serializedStringList)
{
  QStringList result;
  QByteArray byteArray = QByteArray::fromBase64(serializedStringList.toUtf8());
  QDataStream in(&byteArray, QIODevice::ReadOnly);
  in >> result;
  return result;
}
```