# Store QList<QVariant> to PostgreSQL database in Qt

Tags: qt, postgresql

My question is similar to this one: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9817918/qt-qlistqstring-serialization-for-database) except that I don't want to serialize the QList. I want to store a QList as a double precision array in the DB  table.

I am trying the following bindValue command for the variable `val`:

```
query.bindValue( QStrFromSrcEnc( id ), QVariant::fromValue( val ) );
```

where `val`  is QList and `id` is `":value"`

I am executing the following postgres query:

```
"INSERT INTO valtable( type_id, asset_id, value, tag )\n"
            "VALUES ( :typeId, :assetId, :value, :tag )\n"
```

The `value` column of the table is of the type double precision[].

I get the following error, as you can see the 3rd field for `value` is blank which means  `val` wasn't bound correctly.

```
ERROR: syntax error at or near ","
LINE 1: EXECUTE qpsqlpstmt_13e (60, 63, , '')
                                        ^
```

however, if val is simply a QVariant, then it works fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I did a workaround.
I convert the QList List to a QString in a postgres array format (e.g.'{1.32,4.43}').

```
QString valueStr = QStrFromSrcEnc("{");

for(int i=0; i<List.size(); ++i)
{

    valueStr += QString::number( List[i] );
    valueStr += QStrFromSrcEnc(",");
}

valueStr.chop(1);
valueStr += QStrFromSrcEnc("}");
```

then I bind the string value to the `:val` placeholder